# How to get user who authenticated the Git push (to a BitBucket repo)

Tags: git, bitbucket

Please consider below case,

- Git repository is maintained in BitBucket (a.k.a stash).
- Repository is checked out to working directory using http method (i.e. user name password should be given). Say the user name used in this case is "Don"
- gitconfig is modified to say

```
[user]
        email = John@xyz.com
        name = John
```

- Changes are done, committed and pushed to remote repository, (BitBucket http authenticated) by user "William".

Now in a Git blame, user "John" is shown as the author of the change.

**Is there a way to find out the user who actually authenticated the push to the remote repository** ? i.e. "William" in this case.

This seems to be a critical security concern as a user can push (say rogue) changes blaming a another user ("John" in above case). So I am guessing there must be a way to find out the actual user who authenticated the push.

Comment: Git knows nothing of authentication. If people do stuff in bad faith, Git doesn’t care. Authentication here is purely a Bitbucket matter.

Comment: if git cannot provide this, are you aware if BitBucket has the capability to provide this ?

Comment: related https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-questions/Who-really-made-a-commit/qaq-p/621814